# Compiling gtk+3.0 on windows: Can not find staticpixbufloader-gdiplus

Tags: windows, gtk3, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to compile a sample hello-world app for gtk+3.0 on windows using msys2 and mingw64.

I have in part been following this tutorial: http://www.tarnyko.net/repo/gtk3_build_system/tutorial/gtk3_tutorial.htm

When I build I get:

`$ gcc -o gtk3.exe gtk3.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lstaticpixbufloader-gdiplus`

`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` returns:

`-mms-bitfields -pthread -mms-bitfields -I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/fribidi -I/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include -L/mingw64/lib -L/mingw64/lib/../lib -L/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lepoxy -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfribidi -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lz -lpixman-1 -lfontconfig -liconv -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -ldwrite -lgraphite2 -lpng16 -lz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgdiplus -lole32 -ljpeg -ljasper -lm -lstaticpixbufloader-gdiplus -lm -lpng16 -lz -ltiff -lzstd -llzma -ljpeg -lz -lgio-2.0 -lintl -pthread -lintl -lshlwapi -ldnsapi -liphlpapi -lws2_32 -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lz -lgobject-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lffi -lglib-2.0 -lintl -pthread -lws2_32 -lwinmm -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -lpcre`

I can only find one reference to `staticpixbufloader-gdiplus` on my pc, in `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/gdk-pixbuf-2.0.pc`. No file with that as part of it's name is on my PC, and I can find no useful reference to it in my google searches.

I have the `gdk-pixbuf2` package installed.

Any advice on what to try or where to look next would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With some kind guidance from the community I tested an older version of the msys2 gdk-pixbuf2 package.

It turned out it was the mingw-w64-x86_64-gdk-pixbuf2 2.38.0-1 package that was the issue for me. I downgraded to 2.36.9-1 and I was able to compile and run successfully.

I grabbed the xz file from http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/ and downgraded using `pacman -U ./mingw-w64-x86_64-gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.9-1-any.pkg.tar.xz`